# cell variable is nil where value was set collectionview index path

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

i spend lot of time .. but i can't figure out why it is not working .. cell for index path called and set value properly but cell class i found nil value .. if your need any information then let me know .

in my collectionview index path

[image]

in collectionview cell

[image]

here is my code :

for collectionview :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: menuBarItemDetailId, for: indexPath) as! MenuBarItemDetail
        cell.shopCategory = "600"
        print(cell.shopCategory)
        return cell
    }
```

for cell :

```
class MenuBarItemDetail: UICollectionViewCell , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {
    var shopCategory : String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

         print("shopCategory :-> ...i am calling from cell :\(shopCategory)")
}
```

Comment: it is taken optional value use print(cell.shopCategory)!

Comment: yes ! I already  done that one please check 1st image  but no result .. do you meant that one

Comment: @Lalitkumar yes optional  value use that as my first picture

Comment: @cristanlika no need of these in cell class UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate at first because this is collection view cell so all delegates you need to put in your view controller and remove init function. no need. you can use awakeFromNib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `awakeFromNib` method called first and then `cellForRow` .You are assigning the value of variable in `cellForRow` so when first project executes its value is `nil`.

> Solution

1. your variable in your custom cellclass

   ```
   var myVar : String?
   ```
2. Create a method in your custom cellclass

   ```
   func myMethod(str : String){
       myVar = str
       print("var : \(myVar)")        
   }
   ```
3. in `cellForItem`, call your function like this

   ```
   cell.myMethod(str: "343")
   ```

> Output

[image]

Comment: first of all i did not use awakeFromNib anywhere in my project second if so what is that solution . could you guide me what can do ?

Comment: Init method also called first, check it out.

Comment: yes seem . what can i do ? what is the solution please

Comment: @cristanlika Check the solution with output I got. Accept the answer and upvote if it works for you otherwise write your problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you are writing

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseId`entifier: "MenuBarItemDetail", for: indexPath) as! MenuBarItemDetail`
```

At that time "override init(frame: CGRect)"  is called.
and no value is assigned to shopCategory at the time of init that's the reason you are getting nil.

Add a function  "getShopCategory" into  MenuBarItemDetail and when every you want to access the value of shopCategory you can get that using getShopCategory function.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

    class MenuBarItemDetail: UICollectionViewCell  {
        var shopCategory : String?

        func  getShopCategory()  {
         print("shopCategory :-> ...i am calling from cell :\(shopCategory)")
        }


    }
```

Controller Class

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MenuBarItemDetail", for: indexPath) as! MenuBarItemDetail
        cell.shopCategory = "600"
        print(cell.shopCategory)
        cell.getShopCategory()
        return cell
    }
```

cell is the current instance of MenuBarItemDetail so it will return assigned value of shopCategory

Please let me know if it's working for you. 
Thank you